# Prove that the limit of the following complex function doesn't exist

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove the following limit doesn't exist $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}(z/\overline{z})^2$

Approach: I am trying to approach different complex numbers and see if I get a different limits. I am also trying to approach this in polar coordinates, but I think it's useless because as a complex number approaches 0, the angle from the positive axis shouldn't change. All the complex number I have tried yield to the same result.

Comment: If you approach from the real axis $lim_{x\to 0}(\frac{x}{\bar{x}})^2=lim_{x\to 0}(\frac{x}{x})^2=1$. Now if you approach at an angle $2\pi/8$ you find yourself getting $lim_{x\to 0}(\frac{xe^{2\pi i/8}}{xe^{-2\pi i/8}})^2=lim_{x \to 0}(e^{2\pi i/4})^2=e^{\pi i}=-1$. You just need to show that the limits don't coincide when you take the limits from different angles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1) When $z = a$ , $(z/\overline{z})^2 = (z/z)^2 = 1^2  = 1$.

2) When $z = a+ai$,  $(z/\overline{z})^2 = (\frac{a(1+i)}{a(1-i)})^2 = (\frac{(1+i)^2}{2})^2 = (\frac{2i}{2})^2 = i^2 = -1$.

Here $a \in \mathbb R$

Generalisation:

Let $z = Re^{\theta i}$, where $R \in \mathbb R$, $\overline{z} = Re^{-\theta i}$, $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}(z/\overline{z})^2= \lim_{R \rightarrow 0}(\frac{Re^{\theta i}}{Re^{-\theta i}})^2 = \lim_{R \rightarrow 0}(e^{2\theta i})^2 = \lim_{R \rightarrow 0}(e^{4\theta i}) = \cos 4 \theta + i\sin 4 \theta $.

Substituting $\theta$ proper values, and one can get infinitly counterexample.

Comment: @TheMathNoob see what I added.

Comment: Oh I forgot to square the whole thing hahaha

Comment: ok,so that's the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @TheMathNoob Since these two guys are totally different what can you conclude about their similarity.

Comment: the limit can't exist since it must be unique

Comment: @TheMathNoob Yup

Comment: but I am still wondering, if you approach a complex number to 0 in polar coordinates, the angle doesn't change. The only thing that changes is the radius right?

Comment: @TheMathNoob Yes but the radii eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to write $Lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\left(\frac{x+iy}{x-iy}\right)^2$. Approach $(0,0)$ along line $y=mx$ where $m\in\mathbb R$, you will find that $Lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1+im}{1-im}\right)^2$ doesn't exist uniquely as it depends on $m$.