Limit of a $(z/z*)^2$ as $z \to 0:$ Complex Valued function
I have a very basic question it seems, but I couldn't figure it out somehow. I have the following limit to evaluate:
$$\lim_{z\to0} (\dfrac{z}{\bar{z}})^2 = ?$$
Intuitively, one can understand that the limit does not exist. The problem I am having is that I tried to approach zero from the Real axis first and then from the Imaginary axis. They both gave me 1.
$\lim_{x\to0} (\dfrac{x+iy}{x-iy})^2 = (\dfrac{x}{x})^2 = 1$ and
$\lim_{y\to0}$ $(\dfrac{x+iy}{x-iy})^2 = (\dfrac{iy}{-iy})^2=1$.
In this case, it seems like the limit exists, but it does not. How do I approach this from another direction other than the two axes? Also, what might be a more rigorous way instead of trying different directions to see if I will get the same answer?
Thanks in advance.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1876624/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4146409/42969

Please also use MathJax in the title. Note that $z\overline{z}=|z|^2$.

@MartinR and DietrichBurde, Thanks for the help. For some reason, I overlooked these links it seems.

What might be a more rigorous way to prove that limit doesn't exist, then? I don't think choosing random directions to check if they result in the same value is the most rigorous way of going with this.

Just observe $(re^{it}/re^{-it})^2 = e^{4it}$. You are looking for $\lim\limits_{r\to 0}e^{4it}$.
